# Can someone tell me why this isn't working? Css dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am trying to make a dropdown menu using CSS but it isn't working. Can anyone tell me why?  I tried it several different ways and it doesn't want to drop down any menus.

```html
 <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
   <ul>
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="performDrop"><a href="#">The Performer</a></li>
     <ul id="perform">
      <li class="subList"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li class="subList"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li class="subList"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
     </ul>
    <li id="drinkDrop"><a href="#">The Drink-Smith</a></li>
     <ul id="drinks">
      <li class="subList"><a href="#">Wine of the Week</a></li>
      <li class="subList"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
     </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

and here is the CSS which seems to be where the problem is

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin:0;
 text-align: left;
 width:600px;
 float:right;
 padding: 35px 20px 20px 0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap  ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: You need to use JavaScript/jQuery to toggle the dropdown. Pure css also is possible, but you need to use transitions.

Comment: How can you hope for someone else to put the effort to help if you don't even put the effort to properly indent your code and make it readable that way?

Comment: Apart from that, the only allowed direct descendant element in a `ul` is `li`.

Comment: @connexo Can you explain?

Comment: There is no need for either Javascript/jQuery or CSS transitions here. You *can* use CSS transitions to make it a smoother experience, but it is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to nest your `ul` inside of the relavent `li`:

```
<li id="performDrop"><a href="#">The Performer</a>
    <ul id="perform">
        <li class="subList"><a href="#">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li class="subList"><a href="#">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="subList"><a href="#">Videos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here's your working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o4254bav/1/

The only change I made was to move the closing tag for you list item `</li>` to enclose your `<ul>` tag.